# Get the position of maximum value and the respective row element in a Data frame

Tags: r

I created a data frame named "data" and has 100 rows of names and corresponding ages (colnames "NAMES" and "AGES").  Now I try to find the maximum age using the max() function by using
max(data[,"AGES"])

I get the maximum age, but I want to get the position also and the names of the people having the maximum age. And after getting the names of the people of maximum age I want to arrange them alphabetically.. How do I do this?

I tried searching on the net, but wasnt successful in summing the different things up..

Comment: Read An Introduction to R. Then use `which.max` and subsetting and `order`.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: i used which.max and the function returns only one value.. but the problem is that i want all the positions of the maximum value.. not just one..   Example code that i tried 
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "1"  "10" "5"  "5"  "10"
[2,] "10" "4"  "6"  "9"  "4" 
> which.max(x[1,])
[1] 2
>i need both the positions 2  and 5

Comment: `x==max(x)`. Those are really the most basic things you need to know when using R. Please study [R-intro](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) and some tutorials.

Comment: tried x==max(x), but getting the max(x) to be 9 instead of 10! Is there a option that includes the repeating values?

Comment: Is your data really numeric? If you run `x[,"AGES"]` does it appear on screen output as quoted (e.g. "2") or unquoted (e.g.2)? Furtehrmore, what does `class(x[,"AGES"])` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first generate some demo data:

```
data<-data.frame(NAMES=replicate(100, paste(sample(letters, 8, replace=T), collapse="")), AGES=sample(20:60, 100, replace=T))
head(data)

     NAMES AGES
1 oepefudt   21
2 ibmuaemm   49
3 mkockaqu   23
4 whyzomna   59
5 omqqtbsz   35
6 qnbmjmuf   25
```

We can then find the rows that have the maximum age, extract their names, and finally sort them in alphabetical order in a single line:

```
sort(as.character(data$NAMES[data$AGES==max(data$AGES)]))
```

Or maybe more transparently:

```
# Find the maximum age
max.age<-max(data$AGES)
# Which rows have the maximum age value?
ind<-which(data$AGES==max.age)
# Extract the name using the ind from above
persons<-as.character(data$NAMES[ind])
# Sort the names
persons.sorted<-sort(persons)
persons.sorted
```

Would this help?

Comment: hey if u dont mind can u tell me how I do the ordering using the order function? (order the ages in a ascending order as well as alphabetically for the tied ages)'

Comment: Ordering ages by age from the same data as above would be performed, e.g., data$AGES[order(data$AGES)]. Using both AGES and NAMES would be: data$AGES[order(data$AGES, data$NAMES)]. See ?order for more examples. Especially note that you can order some variables in ascending and other in descending order, e.g., data$AGES[order(-data$AGES, data$NAMES)].